# SQL text editor for local visual studio database

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2010, text, editor

In Visual Studio 2010 ultimate I have added a local database to my project. I see how you can use the graphical editor to create tables, but is there a text editor? It appears that there is a text editor for writing queries and I tried to do a create table statement but Visual Studio will not allow this.

What is an alternate text editor I can use to write create table statements and queries? I have used management studio before (more for servers).

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: what are you using to create the database ?

Comment: Visual Studio, I right clicked my solution and clicked add new item and selected a local database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use DB Visualiser (http://www.dbvis.com/); it's free and really good for viewing tables, relationships and executing basic queries.

I don't work for them btw - I'm just a long time happy user!

Cheers,

Neil

Comment: Oh one thing - remember to activate the TCP/IP interface or you cannot connect

Comment: Does this work with a local database item created in visual studio?

Comment: Where do you activate the TCP/IP interface? Inside Visual Studio, or inside DB Visualizer?

Comment: What does this error mean: [CREATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [SQLITE_NOTADB]  File opened that is not a database file (file is encrypted or is not a database)

Comment: DBVisualiser looks great so far. Could you help me out with my most recent post though?

Comment: Sorry - to activate the TCP/IP interface (though I guess you have worked it out by now!); you do it in the SQL Server configuration management.  On the last error you had you have chosen an SQL Lite db not an SQL server one